# How can I change the encoding from utf8 to big endian

Tags: php, php-5.6

How can I change the encoding from utf8 to big-endian only for Arabic characters to send SMS messages through SMS service? This code doesn't work.

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, "UCS-2BE", "auto");
```

Result should look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vjyx.png)

Comment: _“Result should look like this”_ - based on _what input_? And what do you even _mean_ by “should look like this”, that’s just a list of digits, what does that have to do with big endian encoding?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:php-5.6] which is **past end of life and should not be used**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must do the following:

1. check the encoding and the presence of Arabic characters. You can do it like that:

   ```
    //$text - string that you need to convert

    if (mb_detect_encoding ($text) == "UTF-8" && mb_ereg('[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]', $text)) {
               ...
    }
   ```
2. Convert string to USC-2BE encoding.You can use [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function

   ```
   iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2BE", $text)
   ```
3. Then [unpack](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php) to needed format (H*hex - in your case) and convert to [uppercase](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtoupper.php):

   ```
   if (mb_detect_encoding ($text) == "UTF-8" && self::isArabic($text)) {
               $arr = unpack("H*hex", @iconv("UTF-8", "UCS-2BE", $text));
               $text = strtoupper($arr["hex"]);
   }
   ```

That's it. It should work.